# Qt - main() function of referenced project covering main() of the actual project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am making a unit tests Qt project in Qt Creator that references files from the project I want to test. Now, whether I reference classes I want to test through a .pri file or by adding relevant files directly to the SOURCES and HEADERS variables of the unit tests project (and .pri file really seems to do the same anyway, it just contains SOURCES and HEADERS entries), adding files from the main project seems to overwrite the main.cpp in the unit tests project.

What I mean is that when I build and run the uni tests executable, the `main()` function of the original project runs! If I rename either the main.cpp in the original project, or the main.cpp in the unit tests project (which changes its .pro file), then things go smoothly. Well, I can live with such solution, but it makes a bit uncomfortable, because  one day in the future I might accidentally use same names for some files in those two projects and who knows, maybe get errors that will be a nightmare to track down. Beside I'm simply curious as to what's the cause of such behaviour.

Of course the .pri file only includes class headers and cpp files, not the main.cpp of the original application, e.g. in my case:

```
HEADERS += \
    ../Project/fooclass.h

SOURCES += \
    ../Project/fooclass.cpp
```

Also both projects are in directories next to each other, not nested.

Edit: [Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782631/760239) asked to see my test's pro file, so here it is:

Test's pro file:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
QT += testlib

TARGET = Tests
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
    test_class.cpp \
    main_unit_tests.cpp

HEADERS += \
    AutoTest.h \
    test_class.h \

include(trial.pri)
```

Trial.pri contains files from main project I want to test. main_unit_tests.cpp (renamed from original main.cpp as an ad-hoc solution) contains:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "AutoTest.h"

TEST_MAIN
```

`TEST_MAIN` is defined in AutoTest.h as

```
#define TEST_MAIN \
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) \
  { \
    return AutoTest::run(argc, argv); \
}
```

Visit this [page](http://qtcreator.blogspot.ca/2010/04/sample-multiple-unit-test-project.html) for the description of what does AutoTest.h do. In short it makes running multiple unit test with Qt framework a bit less hassle.

---

Edit:
pro. file of the main project (i.e. one containing classes I want to test) is:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = Project
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    fooclass.cpp

HEADERS += \
    fooclass.h
```

And it lies on the path: ...\Unit_Test\Project
Whereas the unit tests project lies on the path: ...\Unit_Test\Tests
Right now things work fine as files defining `main()` are different in both projects. As soon as I rename them so they're the same, the unit tests projects excutes main function of the original project.

Comment: Could you please show both .pro and .pri, please. If both projects are in unrelated directories and you don't include the `main()` for the the basic app, I can hardly see how this is possible.

Comment: There is no way I can see how this could happen... If you want me to look further, please provide a .tar/.zip with you complete sources.

Comment: @Koying - http://www.mediafire.com/?32q82e3h77hw1m0
And as soon as I change main.cpp in the 'Tests' project to whatever other name things work as expected. I was able to reproduce it with a few other small projects, doesn't seem to be a one-off glitch.

Comment: There are traces of MSVC2010 in the makefiles. How are you actually compiling the projects?

Comment: @Koying - I'm using a MS Visual Studio C++ toolchain under QT Creator for my builds. What I posted here doesn't require it, but in general I need to work with dlls compiled for Visual Studio, hence can't go for default MinGW tools.

Answer (score 0):

Filenames don't matter, what matters is how many main() functions are included in the build of your unit test. Don't include the main.cpp of your actual application in the SOURCES of the unit test project, and you should be fine.

Comment: the main.cpp of the basic application was never included in sources of the unit tests project. The main.cpp of the unit application can't be removed as there is then no file defining main() function (unless of course I define main in a different file, which is what I'm doing now).

Comment: Use the QTEST_MAIN() to define the test's main function. I don't see how the basic application's main() function can be run if it is not built for the test? How does your test's .pro file look like?

Answer (score 0):

GNU make utility is not the best.

If your obj files for both actual app and tests projects created in same folder, it is possible that wrong `main.o` will be linked.

Make sure, your test project and actual app project build folders differ, or simply do not use `main.cpp` filename twice.

Comment: Build directories, as well as source directories (apart for referenced files of course) are different.